# Black Duck SynopSys version limitation issue

Tags: azure-devops, blackduck

We have integrated Azure Pipeline with Black Duck Synopsys task and it's limits up to 10 versions. For every pipeline runs versions will be created and pipeline runs successfully up to 10 runs only. For 11th run pipeline will be failed because of version limitation in Black Duck. Here we can delete the older versions manually in Black Duck but instead of doing manually in black duck, is it possible to do automatically through ADO pipeline by adding any task ?

In short, can we use any powershell or other tasks in the pipeline which automatically deletes the versions when count reach to 10 ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using the Blackduck API to remove a project programmatically. This is a REST API so could be called from Azure DevOps Pipelines.

You first need the UI to generate an API token. This can then be used to generate a bearer token to be used with the API to remove the older project versions.

Once you have logged into BlackDuck the full API guide is under the help menu.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I spoke to sales and support about it.

 There are 3 solutions :

- raise the limit (paid)
- It seems that Blackduck could clean old versions automatically
- using API, list versions and remove old ones